# Why I get this Error? (State Space)

Tags: matlab, matrix, simulink, state-space

Could someone explain me what I must change in my model?

[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgJn6.png)

Comment: is this question on programming really? or is it so generic, that it could belong to anything you'd like...

Comment: I am sorry, I thought I can ask questions like this at this forum...

Comment: You can ask clear and concise questions on the Q&A site, but not very broad and unspecified questions like this. What's wrong? Why do you need to change anything? What are you trying to achieve? Any error messages? Those screenshots are a bit hard to see. Please try to include only necessary information, and all necessary information.

Comment: If you click on the picture you can see everything you ask. (Picture isn't hard to see, there is a zoom button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages are pretty clear and self-explanatory. The reason you get the error is because `B` is of dimension `4x2` and you are trying to do `B * Xr` where `Xr` is of dimension 1. According to your equation, you need to do `B*U` where `U = [dXr/dt; Xr];`. However, using the derivative block is never a good idea in Simulink if you can avoid it, especially with a step input. Think about how you want to formulate the inputs to your state-space.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works now. Could you suggest me how can I avoid the Derivate Block? If no. Should I use Matlab instead of Simulink?

Comment: Right now I have two inputs U = [dXr/dt; Xr]. Maybe I could avoid the velocity dXr/dt and not taking into consideration?

Comment: The derivative of a step input is the impulse function, which is not easy numerically speaking. Can you use different inputs or rewrite your state-space equations to avoid having to take the derivative of step input?